# How to debug MeteorJS Cordova application?

Tags: cordova, meteor

We can build Cordova application from Meteor version 0.9.2.

How can we debug it? Client & server code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug the server-part in the same way as you would do it with a regular node app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrmdbEvoAPg

<del>For the Cordova app, there are no good ways for step-though debugging yet, but console.logs appear in the terminal of running app.

Ideally, I would develop my app against the browser and then test it on mobile emulator in the end.</del>

Refer to the docs: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Comment: How do you develop the app against the browser if you're using Cordova only code such as Meteoric?

Answer (score 5):

Came here because I was looking for a similar solution. I found out there actually is a way.

It depends on your device but if you have Chrome installed on an Android and on your computer the steps are the same as you would debug a mobile website on your device.

1. Plug your device to your computer.
2. In Chrome go to chrome://inspect
3. Open your app on your device
4. On the bottom on the chrome page it should say something like "WebView in ..."
5. Click the inspect-link.
6. HAPPY DEBUGGING :)

For iOS there is a similar way with Safari.
http://blog.differential.com/debug-a-meteor-cordova-app/

For an extended guide on how to debug on your mobile phone: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

For the server-code you can use the terminal like you normally would.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor site has all of the information on this:
https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html

Debugging Android in Chrome:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/#remote-debugging-on-android-with-chrome-devtools
[image]

The one thing however that was not mentioned is how to view the "client side native logs" -- to do this for Android, just run this command in terminal after running `meteor run android-device`:

`adb logcat`

See the Meteor docs for iOS debugging